# Proper way to set String[] to a TextView

Tags: android, arrays, string, textview

I have an array of strings and I want to concatenate these string and set the result to a `TextView`. Currently I do it with this code:

```
String[] strings = getStrings();
textView.setText(Arrays.toString(strings).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code. Replace `", "` with a delimiter you would like to use.

```
TextUtils.join(", ", Arrays.asList(strings));
```